# Android Studio 4.2, Attach debugger dialog, Debug type control disabled

Tags: android, android-studio

There is an "Debug type" control in Attach Debugger dialog in Android Studio. Earlier, I was able to select Java/Native/Dual debug type there when attaching debugger.

But now (Android Studio 4.2 RC1) it is disabled. Every time I want to change debug type, I have to go to "Edit Debug/Run configuration", select my current configuration, go to "Debugger" tab and select debugger type there.
That a lot of reduntant clicks.

Is there a way to enable Debug type control in Attach debugger dialog?
Or do I have to duplicate Debug/Run configurations for each debug type?